# Which is the best open source mail account backup solution for Ubuntu mail server?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, email-server

We have a mail server (SMTP, IMAP , spam assassin , ClamAV ) running on Ubuntu and there are more than 200 mail accounts. We are looking for a backup solution for mail, which will allow us to take the **backup of individual accounts**, as per our backup policy.  The situation is that around 25 of the accounts need frequent backups while the rest are not that important.

So can anyone suggest a good solution, preferably open source. If it has a GUI interface it would be preferred.

Comment: I can suggest [backuppc](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) for remote backup which we use for the exact same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

We use rsync. Our mailstore is mdbox, which gives us the opportunity to just sync those folders we want.